# scheduleAtFixedRate alternative in Scheduler (since ActorPing is deprecated)?

Tags: scala, lift

I was looking for the alternative to scheduleAtFixedRate in Scheduler. 
Couldn't find. Was it removed for any specific reason when ActorPing 
was deprecated? Some kind of performance issues?

Comment: look what i stumbled upon! :P I wonder if the place where we worked together is now actually finally starting to look ahead to use scala and rubies :P or is it your fun time coding :) PS: i know this is not the place for this comment, but could not help it!

Comment: Practiced in my fun time coding but trying to push it at work.

Answer (score 0):

It could lead to deadlock so for the sake of users safety it has been removed.

Comment: Hi Lukasz, I stubled upon this limitation, too. So what is the "safe" way of doing periodic execution, short of just using the Java ones? Thanks

Comment: You can start first ping during initialization and then schedule rest inside actor processing code. If you need code for that let me know I'll dig something out.